# arouse vs rouse (looks really same) could be any different usage?

Tags: verbs

ex) arouse sb's interest
arouse sb's curiosity
arouse sby's anger
The whole community was aroused by the crime.

ex) rouse sb from sleep. Nicky roused her with a gentle nudge. A lot of people were roused to action by the appeal. to rose sb's anger. Chris is not easily roused.

very similar.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the direct object. You *rouse* a person, you *arouse* a feeling. When you arouse a person, it's sexual.

Answer (score 1):

Rouse essentially means to wake someone up. e.g He was roused of his slumber by the loud noise

However, it also means to make someone angry or excited.

arouse means to stimulate someone or to stimulate a feeling in someone

Her dance moves aroused me(sexually)

Her lectures aroused a lot of interest among the students

To put it simply, arouse is most commonly used when talk about feelings whereas rouse is used mostly in terms of physically waking someone